# Pass in uppercase after "-" (indexOf)

Tags: java

In an exercise to make, I must to change the character after the dash in uppercase.

For example -> `jean-louis becomes Jean-Louis`

I know to change in uppercase the first caractere but after the dash I don't understand.

```
String name= null;                      // enter the name
String letterSlice = null;              // slice the first letter
String letterSliceUpper = null;         // first letter in uppercase
String remainingLetters = null;         // remaining letters
int dashIndex = 0;                      // dash


System.out.print("Enter your name please : ");
name = input.next();

letterSlice = name.substring(0,1);
letterSliceUpper = letterSlice.toUpperCase();
remainingLetters = name.substring(1);

dashIndex = name.indexOf("-");

if(remainingLetters.indexOf("-") != -1 ){

}

System.out.print(letterSliceUpper.concat(remainingLetters));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `jean` is not after the dash...

Comment: `dashIndex` is set to the position of the first dash (or `-1` if no dash). Add one for index of character after the dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by constructing a `StringBuilder` (a mutable collection of characters), capitalize the first letter and then search for `-` character(s). Capitalizing every character following a `-`. Like,

```
String name = "jean-louis-patrice";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)));
int p = 0;
while ((p = sb.indexOf("-", p + 1)) != -1) {
    if (p + 1 < sb.length()) {
        sb.setCharAt(p + 1, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(p + 1)));
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Outputs

```
Jean-Louis-Patrice
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another solution using RegEx

```
String str = "jean-louis-patrice";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^.|-.)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
       matcher.appendReplacement(result, matcher.group().toUpperCase());
}

matcher.appendTail(result);

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder instead of creating a lot of String(Memory efficient). Try below:

```
System.out.print("Enter your name please : ");
name = input.next();
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(name.length());
String words[] = name.split("-"); 
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){  
 result.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0))).append(words[i].substring(1)).append("-");  
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the index of `-` in order to replace the following character e.g.

```
int indexOfDash = name.indexOf('-');
```

Besides that I would convert the String into a Char array. It's way easier to manipulate. Something like

```
char[] charArray = name.toCharArray();
charArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[0]);
if (indexOfDash != -1) {
    charArray[indexOfDash + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[indexOfDash + 1]);
}
String newName = String.valueOf(charArray);
System.out.println(newName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            String s = "word-word";
            String[] list = s.split("-");

            String res = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                String _temp = list[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                _temp += list[i].substring(1);
                res += _temp;

                if( i != list.length -1 )
                {
                    res += "-";
                }
            }

            System.out.println(res);    
        }
    }
```